# Run time errors in eclipse android application [unfortunately application has stopped]

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime-error, numberformatexception

I am facing an issue in my app ,when I click the button inside my app it gives the error

***(unfortunately application has stopped)*,**

and these are problems in Logcat :

please help me out ,what exactly is the issue ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7xoa.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGk8V.png]

i solved it , thnx guys

Comment: Post your code where you got this errors>

Comment: We don't have any information to work with.

Comment: don't post image/link. put your code here

Comment: You are parsing an integer which is not integer. If you are using `Integer.parseInt()` method, then please make sure, only input it get are `numeral`, otherwise, it will always throw exception, like it is doing right now.

Comment: post your button click code where you get NumberFormat exception

Comment: please post your code....

Answer (score 0):

You have an editText which accepts inputs other than numbers also.
I assume you are trying to convert the value in the editText to an Integer using

```
Integer.parseInt ((String) EditText.getText());
```

1. Either restrict the input in the editText to numbers only.
2. Or, Handle Number format Exception gracefully with an appropriate error message!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to parse a value starting "android.widget.EditText" - which suggests you may have code like this:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(editText.toString());
```

That's not going to get the text of the `EditText` - for that, you want to call [`getText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29):

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
```